# discord,py: AttributeError: 'Context' object has no attribute 'reference'

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord.py

(Insert greetings)

I wanted to make the discord bot reply to a message which was replied to in the command message,below is the code so far:

```
@bot.command(brief="Iri? Bilang Bos!", description="Iri? Bilang Bos!")
async def iri(ctx):
    ref = ctx.reference
    x=['https://i.imgur.com/8mfw6Nv.jpg', 'https://tenor.com/view/iri-bilang-bos-spell-power-up-skill-gif-17176211', 'https://i.imgur.com/hOvruLZ.jpg']
    await ctx.delete()
    await ctx.send(random.choice(x), reference=ref)
```

This raises the exception AttributeError: 'Context' object has no attribute 'reference'

How do i solve this? Thanks.

Comment: also I need to know how to delete the command message, the code raises the exception: AttributeError: 'Context' object has no attribute 'delete'

Comment: maybe first check documentation - or use `print( dir(ctx) )` to see all avaliable properties and functions in object `ctx`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have the right idea but didn't look into documentation enough. Usually if you don't know what attribute you need to use it's helpful to search in the [documentation](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/).

1. [`Context`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ext/commands/api.html?highlight=context#discord.ext.commands.Context) doesn't have attribute `reference`. That is because [`reference`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Message.reference) is an attribute of our [`message`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Message). Luckily for us context (`ctx`) has a `message` attribute: [`ctx.message`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ext/commands/api.html?highlight=context#discord.ext.commands.Context.message). We use this to to get the `message` object which we then use to get the `reference` attribute: `ctx.message.reference`.
2. The same goes for the `delete` method. `Context` object doesn't have `delete` method so we first need to get the `message` object: `ctx.message` and then use the [`delete`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Message.delete) method of the `message` object: `await ctx.message.delete()` (We have to use await because the `delete` method is asynchronous)

*Note: It's usually good practise to give your variables meaningful names. It improves the readability of your code. That's why I changed your `x` variable to `choices`*

So the end result should be something like this:

```py
@bot.command(brief="Iri? Bilang Bos!", description="Iri? Bilang Bos!")
async def iri(ctx):
    ref = ctx.message.reference
    choices = ['https://i.imgur.com/8mfw6Nv.jpg', 'https://tenor.com/view/iri-bilang-bos-spell-power-up-skill-gif-17176211', 'https://i.imgur.com/hOvruLZ.jpg']
    await ctx.message.delete()
    await ctx.send(random.choice(choices), reference = ref)
```

Hopefully this answers your question :)

Comment: thanks man, worked well. I actually checked around the documentation, found the message object in ctx, and then tried just message.reference and message.delete, but that didn't work, hence why I asked here. appreciate the note too, kinda reminds me of how lazy i am hehe. cheers!